# DynamoDB from aws-java-sdk not complete under gradle

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, gradle, amazon-dynamodb

i'm trying to connect to my DynamoDB using java AWS sdk. I'm following tutorial on [Amazons' Java getting started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.01.html), but I can't do it.

I have `compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.122'` in gradle dependecies, and I can import in my code `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB`, but i can't import `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder` which is needed to create AmazonDynamoDB class according to the tutorial, furthermore AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder is present in documetation, so it's not deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Compiles fine for me. Maybe you just a have a typo somewhere. Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
group 'DynamoTest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.122'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, no typo. I've copy pasted, and even alt+enter don't help.

Comment: In the Project Tool Window can you navigate to the External Libraries entry. If you expand that do you have a `Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.122` entry?

Comment: And if you do can you see the `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder` class inside that.

Comment: Another thing you can try is building from the command line. If you open a terminal at the level of your project and type `gradle build`. Does it build your code? If you can't build from the command line than possibly Gradle isn't setup correctly.

Comment: I have 1.10.77 version and i don't have AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder there

Comment: Cool. The 1.10.77 version doesn't work for me either. It doesn't look like that version contains those classes. Can you use a later version?

Comment: Looking on Github that class was added in version 1.11.16 https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/commits/b3127332399ad4d2dd6c047772027b496ba7dbce/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.java

Comment: Seems like IntelliJ is out of sync. If you have 1.11.122  in your build.gradle but version 1.10.77 in the IntelliJ External Libraries entry.

Comment: Might be easiest to re-import the project. If you close the project and then go File Open and navigate to the build.gradle file inside the project and select that. It should prompt you to open the file as a Project. Click `Ok` and when it asks you if you want to overwrite the existing project select `yes`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142421/discussion-between-will-humphreys-and-z-dna).